# How do I perform multiple range queries within the same partition?

Tags: cassandra, cql

We would like to retrieve several columns in different ranges **for the same partition**.
Currently our query looks like (`key` is the **partition key**. `column1` is a **clustering column**). `SELECT column1, value FROM tablename WHERE key = ?key AND column1 >= ?sliceStart AND column1 < ?sliceEnd`.
The query works, however often times it returns more data than needed for the application because application doesn't need the whole slice but only some smaller parts inside that slice operation.

We tried to change the approach to use the same query but querying for multiple smaller slices asynchronously. We found out that in our situation fetching 10 columns via a single slice query is `3.6` times faster than fetching 10 columns via separate smaller parallel CQL queries (using DataStax Java Driver 4.16.0).

We also tried to rewrite the query to fetch the same 10 columns via a single CQL query but using `IN` statement. I.e. `SELECT column1, value FROM tablename WHERE key = ?key AND column1 IN (?column1, ?column2, ?column3, ?column4, ..., ?column10)`. We found out that in our situation this single query is just 17-20% slower than `SELECT column1, value FROM tablename WHERE key = ?key AND column1 >= ?sliceStart AND column1 < ?sliceEnd`, but it performs much faster than 10 separate CQL range queries.

Unfortunately, due to application requirements we can's use simple equality comparison, and instead we need to retrieve all columns in specified ranges. In other words, we would like to have an ability to select multiple column ranges for the same `key` (partition key). Ideally we would use `OR` statement but it isn't supported in CQL. CQL also doesn't support ranges inside `IN` statement.

I.e. this query isn't supported by CQL right now:
`SELECT column1, value FROM tablename WHERE key = ?key AND (column1 >= ?sliceStart1 AND column1 < ?sliceEnd1 OR column1 >= ?sliceStart2 AND column1 < ?sliceEnd2 OR ...)`

Neither do this query is supported:
`SELECT column1, value FROM tablename WHERE key = ?key AND column1 IN (range(?sliceStart1, ?sliceEnd1), range(?sliceStart2, ?sliceEnd2), range(?sliceStart3, ?sliceEnd3), ...)`

What other approaches could be used to query multiple column ranges for the same partition key?

Answer (score 2):

> *We found out that in our situation fetching 10 columns via a single slice query is 3.6 times faster than fetching 10 columns via separate smaller parallel CQL queries (using DataStax Java Driver 4.16.0).*

Parallel async queries on smaller slices would be a recommended solution,  unfortunately here if I understand correctly you are targeting the same partition. As such, even if you split into smaller slices the same nodes get the load, and performance is not improved.

> *We also tried to rewrite the query to fetch the same 10 columns via a single CQL query but using IN statement.*

Avoid `IN` statements. The load is moved from your machine to the coordinator, this coordinator will need to distribute the query as you would do yourself.

> *`OR` keyword not supported.*

The CQL language is in evolution with support of NOT and Vector Search in [CEP-29](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CASSANDRA/CEP-29%3A+CQL+NOT+operator) and `CEP-30` but I am not aware of the OR

**Proposed Solution**:

As described above the recommended approach is async queries of smaller slices. If the performance impact is too important for you there are 2 approaches I can think of:

- Keep the first query that works but filter at application side in memory. It is not as bad as it sounds.
- Tuning (what causing the contention on smaller slices ? CPU on node, execution pool... i would investigate and increase when possible).

Comment: Thank you @clunven for your advice. Would you be able to comment on this statement please?
> Avoid IN statements. The load is moved from your machine to the coordinator, this coordinator will need to distribute the query as you would do yourself.

Does the coordinator node distribute load of IN query to different nodes if the query touches only a single row? In our situation we always touch only 1 row. As I said, using 10 async queries is 3.6 times slower for the same environment than using a single query fetching the same data. We can scale machines vertically, but it just additional cost.

Comment: Coordinator distribute queries indeed per partitions, so with an IN Clause and X items not in same partition, coordinator will trigger X sub queries (and related CONSISTENCY LEVEL requirements)

Comment: Yes, but my question is about same row queries. If we query same row than it means we query same partition. Thus, `IN` operator is beneficial for same row (or even same partition) queries. My purpose is to find a way to get multiple slices of the same row. Not to query multiple keys in different partitions.

Comment: I fixed the question by emphasizing that `key` is a partition key and `column` is a clustering column. Thus, a CQL query always touches just one row, but we need several different slices of that row (i.e. we need to get several columns in several different ranges).

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is no, it is not possible to perform multiple range queries in a single `SELECT` statement by design.

The reason it is not possible to do this is quite intentional.

When I think about what you're trying to achieve, two things come to mind: either (1) you got your data model wrong, or (2) you have an analytics use case.

The reason this query performs fast is because the data is ordered sequentially on disk so there is no additional disk seek required:

```
SELECT ... FROM table WHERE key = ? AND column1 >= ? AND column1 < ?
```

My suggestion is that you do the additional filtering on the client side to limit the results. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the input @erick-ramirez. It is a BigTable data model which we are leveraging in JanusGraph (see link: https://docs.janusgraph.org/advanced-topics/data-model/ ). Honestly, I don't fully understand the intention of supporting `IN` operator but not supporting multi-range operations. If the IN operator touches the same row, the query shouldn't be split to multiple partitions (as far as I understand). The same should be applied to range operations. Thus, there is no much reason for not supporting multi-range operations for the same row in Cassandra. I can be wrong though.

Comment: I think you've mixed terminologies between "partition" and "row" -- each partition can have one or more rows. It is fine to use the `IN()` operator when the query is restricted to a single partition. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. From your comment I got that using `IN()` withing the same row (even withing the same partition) is fine. Do you think then that a multi-range queries is a valid feature request (if they are constrained to the same partition)? Do you think it's OK to ask Cassandra community about this feature or do you think there are any intentions to not support same-partition multi-range queries in Cassandra?